# Why Facebook URL suddenly decrease the number of like/share?

Tags: facebook

I have a landing page what got 9.2k likes 2 days ago

http://cradiff.com/saiyan-ghost-warrior

But suddenly yesterday I check and see it 's only have 17 likes. I don't know why it show like that. Here are some tasks what I did right before the day I see the changes what may effect this problem

- I run facebook ads $40 for this link on my facebook page. Maybe this make the number of likes/share increase too much?
- I use this tool to clear cache until it show the URL is listed in review list https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ . Because this tool doesn't get the last html so that I submit it around 5 times until it is locked

Other than that, everything 's fine. It 's the URL what I have to get the players in game share to earn coins. It 's invested a lot of time and money before it can reach to 9.2k.

Can anyone help me about this?

Comment: It is working fine now with 9.2k. Not sure why, maybe something about system need time to update.

Comment: _“It 's the URL what I have to get the players in game share to earn coins”_ – you are __not allowed__ to reward users for sharing. You should go read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy) – point 4.15 says, _“Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions.”_ So you should __stop__ that practice right now, before you get your app blocked for this violation.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I will bring it to team. But I guess it shouldn't relate to Facebook Policy because it is not facebook apps.

Comment: Facebook is on way driving me crazy. My other URLs suddenly lost all of likes today again http://cradiff.com/saiyan-blast-war/ (more than 500 likes) and http://cradiff.com/skybot-x-warrior/ ( more than 100 likes). I have no idea why.

Comment: Facebook regularly removes likes they think are “bought” or acquired in any other way that is not allowed. And if you are violating policies already by rewarding users for sharing, then you should not be too surprised if Facebook takes action.

Comment: Wow, it 's too bad. Then we shouldn't spend money for facebook ads to push likes/shares because it will be reset somedays. Thanks CBroe.